# Cannot add a Kivy Scatter widget into a Carousel

Tags: android, kivy

I am trying to create a carousel where each image is added to a Scatter or ScatterLayout before adding to the carousel.  I want to resize the image with touch gestures.  The app is for an android phone.

However, I get an error that I Cannot add the scatter widget since it already has a parent.

```
Cannot add <kivy.uix.scatter.ScatterLayout object at 0x7fb9b903def0>, 
it already    has a parent kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout
object at 0x7fb9b8e21530>.
```

I can  add one image to a scatter widget and it stretches.  But with more than one image, when I try to insert the scatter or the scatterlayout between the carousel and the image, the error results.

the user needs to stretch the image (zoom in) on each carousel page if necessary.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import ScatterPlane
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

one_image = False
scatter = ScatterLayout(do_rotation=False)
carousel = Carousel(direction='right', loop=True)
data_dir_receipt = 'data/receipts'
prefix = '02_february_2015_receipts-all-*'
    if one_image is True:
        prefix = '02_february_2015_receipts-all-1.png'
        filename = join(data_dir_receipt, prefix)
        image = AsyncImage(source=filename, allow_stretch=True)
        scatter.add_widget(image)
        return scatter
    else:
        for filename in glob(join(data_dir_receipt, prefix)):
            image = AsyncImage(source=filename, allow_stretch=True)
            scatter.add_widget(image)
            carousel.add_widget(scatter)
        return carousel
```

Comment: could you show some code and elaborate more on error details?

Comment: The fix was rather easy once I determined that the problem was in the for loop.  I wasn't creating a new 'scatter' with every trip through the loop.  Just add scatter = ScatterLayout(do_rotation=False) before the scatter.add_widget(image).